# How to make a batter that is hard and hold up to sauce

Tags: deep-frying, restaurant-mimicry

I am trying to recreate Beijing Beef like they have at Panda Express.
Most copycat recipes are recommending a batter made from some combination of cornstarch and flour.  I am finding that the batter is too delicate and quickly turns to mush when mixed in with the sauce.

The batter on the Panda Express beef is quite thick and hard, almost like a rock so it holds up to the sauce well, although I would say it is not the most crisp of batters.

Do any of you have any ideas of ingredients/techniques that can produce that kind of heavy and hard batter?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds more like they're frying, then baking the beef in the oven to finish it.

Fry the battered beef until in floats (to ensure it cooks all of the way through,) then bake in a 350° oven until it reaches your desired crispness. The longer it bakes the harder it should get.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I think I see how this could fit in.  It looks like they are frying  par-fried frozen beef in the store so I am guessing that they fry the beef, bake it or harden it by some other process and then freeze for final frying in-store.  I will give your idea a try and see how it goes.

Comment: Let me know how it turns out.